# Recursion: subset sum algorithm setting value in parameters

Tags: c++, recursion, subset-sum

How do I reset the value of `blockIndex` to its inital state when I call the method?

Say if I call it and pass in the value 4. I check if that value is greater than 9, if not I add the element at `pos(0)`. But in tracing my function I see that it adds all the values of the vector. I just want it to add 1 element, then when it check if it is greater than 9, and it is not, revert it back to the initial value. How do I do this?

```
int NumCriticalVotes :: CountCriticalVotes(Vector<int> & blocks, int blockIndex)
{
    if (blockIndex >= 9 && blocks.isEmpty())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (blocks.isEmpty()) //Fail case
    {
        return 0;
    } else {

        int element = blocks.get(0);
        Vector<int> rest = blocks;
        rest.remove(0);
        return CountCriticalVotes(rest, blockIndex) || CountCriticalVotes(rest, blockIndex + element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your recursion method code? Did you put any stop condition to your recursion method?

Comment: You can take out `&& blocks.isEmpty()` in `if (blockIndex >= 9 && blocks.isEmpty())`.

Comment: @Tom, As a first comment, didn't you mean to write, in the last return `... || element + CountCriticalVotes(rest, blockIndex)`? In other words, why are you mixing the *value* of an element of the vector with the indices? It is not really clear from the code. Anyway, even if that is the case, the code can be improved. Also, as you are passing `blockIndex` by copy, it will "revert back" to its value when the function returns (on the caller, that is).